# Cannot load angular.dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

During the reproduction of this example, something strange happend: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_by_example/tree/master/example/angular/basics/conditionally_switch_between_dom_elements

So created a plain Dart project in WebStorm, added angular.dart, copied the example. Everything works well, if the files are "web" directory.

BUT, after I moved the three files into a switch subdirectory, I have the following problem:
An error occurred loading file: package:angular/angular.dart

Do you have any idea? What did I missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you added the subdirectory after you ran `pub get` then it may not have the packages symlink folder. Try running `pub get` (from your apps root directory) again which should generate any missing packages in subdirectories that may have been added, without re-downloading any dependencies.